# CXF: Cloneable classes from wsdl2java?

Tags: java, cxf, deep-copy, cloneable

Is it possible to have CXF's wsdl2java emit cloneable classes?  Maybe via some option or a plug-in?

What I need to do is copy by value a rather complex schema structure from one object tree to another and would rather not get/set each member value by hand or touch the generated classes by hand.

/Björn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I've implemented and contributed an XJC plugin that emits cloneable classes:  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-3354

Comment: After implementing this cxf-xjc-cloneable plugin I've found [CC-XJC](http://ccxjc.sourceforge.net/) which does a better job handling the standard Java Collections which don't implement Cloneable, so CC-XJC uses Cloneable where possible and then iterates over all Java Collections instances and appropriately calls `.clone()` on their elements. 

If I'd already found CC-XJC I wouldn't have implemented my own plugin but it was a fun exercise :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you avoid Cloneable, and rather have the emitted classes be serializable and serialize and deserialize the class(es) to clone them. [Here](http://markmail.org/message/aw52wgp6bdpwo5rx) are some instructions on how to do that with CXF, although I never tried it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You COULD write an XJC plugin to do this.   CXF does have a couple XJC plugins to do various things that you could use as a model.  (and maybe submit back to CXF)

Comment: That indeed occurred to me.  If I understand things correctly then it should be enough to add _ implements Cloneable _ to each class.

I haven't yet tried the serializing / deserializing way mentioned here...